# Using interface name as Variable type

Tags: solidity

In solidity, see below code ..... How is that the interface name is being used as variable type ?
See the comments in below code

```
pragma solidity 0.8.11;

import "../interfaces/ISpool.sol";
// ... other imports

abstract contract VaultBase is IVaultBase, VaultImmutable, SpoolOwnable, SpoolPausable, BaseConstants {
    using Bitwise for uint256;
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    /* ========== STATE VARIABLES ========== */

    /// @notice The central Spool contract
    ISpool internal immutable spool;   // ISpool is interface name and it is
                                       // being used as variable type. What this means ?

}
```

ISpool interface:

```
interface ISpool is ISpoolExternal, ISpoolReallocation, ISpoolDoHardWork, ISpoolStrategy, ISpoolBase {}
```

How is that the interface name is being used as variable type ?

Answer (score 1):

Interface type variables work the same way as [Contract type](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/types.html#contract-types) variables.

They serve as as pointer to the specified address, assuming that there is a contract deployed on this address that implements this interface.

Example: If the `ISpool` interface declares a function `foo(uint256) external returns (bool)`, your contract can call this function and assign the return value directly:

```
spool = ISpool(address(0x123));
bool result = spool.foo(1);
```

If the specified address doesn't implement this specific function that you're trying to call, the call fails with an exception.